# Vue on change on Html.DropDownList MVC 5

Tags: html, vue.js, asp.net-mvc-5, html-helper

here is my dropdownlist

```
@Html.DropDownList("UAPs", (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewData["UAPs"], new { @class = "form-control form-contro-sm", @id = "uap", @v_model = "uap" })
```

I'm already binding the selected value, however, i need to create an event for on change to trigger ajax call to refresh the table for filtering data but i can't seem to manage to bind it

```
@v_on:change = ""
```

this does not work

Comment: I'd would recommend `v_change` but for me it makes the event handler bound to ALL of my input controls. Currently trying to figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem using variables.

```
@{ 
 var attribs = new Dictionary<string, object>();
 attribs.Add("class", "form-control form-contro-sm");
 attribs.Add("id", "uap");
 attribs.Add("v-model", "uap");
 attribs.Add("v-on:change", "myFunction()");
 }

@Html.DropDownList("UAPs", (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewData["UAPs"], htmlAttributes: attribs)
```